# SQL script within subquery (Big Query)?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery, sql-scripts

Is there a way to have SQL scripts within a subquery ?

For example:

```sql
select col_1, col_2, count(*) from (
Declare max_radius INT64;
set max_radius = 250;

select * from my_table
where radius <  max_radius
)
group by col_1,col_2
```

In my case it is not possible to move the variable declaration outside of the subquery.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular example, you could use a CTE to define the parameter values:

```
with params as (
      select 250 as max_radius
     )
select t.col_1, t.col_2, count(*)
from params p cross join
     my_table t
where t.radius < p.max_radius
group by t.col_1, t.col_2;
```

Comment: Yes, this was my first though but if my_table is huge (and in reality it is) the cross join will have a very poor performance because it will duplicate the params for each row in mytable. And I wanted to workaround that problem by using a variable.

Comment: @Yairh . . . The cross join should be trivial because there is only one row.